# JavaScript: RegEx - Do not return match1 match2 etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to adopt this regex for my needs:

```
(?:^|\s)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+(?=\.).)?(?<name>.*).(?<tld>(?<=\.)\w+)
```

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/lI2lB4/2

I would like to return a match for all entries like:

- www.example.com
- example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

but not for

- example.
- http://www.example
- www.example

Now the regex shown above is working fine, but it returns different matches (Match 1, Match 2, ...) - but would like to get only one result: `Matching` or `not matching`.

As a result I would like to use

```
regExDomain.test($regExDomain.test(input.val()))
{
console.log('valid');
}
else
{
console.log('invalid');
}
```

The problem is: The regEx above seems always to return "valid".

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: How are you using it? What language? If the regex is working fine, then the problem is in how you use it.

Comment: Hello. I'm using it in JS (jQuery). If the regex returns true, I'm triggering other functions. The given regEx seems to be always true, because the functions are always triggered... I added my initial question to explain a little better...

Comment: Why does it matter how many matches it returns? If it returns any matches then it matched, else it did not. You're using `()` which will capture data, hence the multiple matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test()` function of Regex class should be enough to validate whether the input matches the pattern.

You could do something like this:

```
var pattern = /^(http[s]?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.[^\.]{2,3}$/
var regex = new RegExp(pattern);

for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    if ( regex.test( $("#text"+i).text() ) )
      $("#isMatch"+i).html("MATCHES");
  else
    $("#isMatch"+i).html("DOESN'T MATCH");
}
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jyu16m89/1/

The above example will return false for the extended domains (e.g. ".digital" or ".menu" ). If you want to include it in your pattern, replace `{2,3}` by `+`

If you want to include subdomains/folders in your pattern (e.g. returning true for entries like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/`), remove the dollar sign (this not limiting the string to end there).

Answer (score 0):

You have a grouped regex so it will return `match[n]` where n is the number of groups that matched. If nothing matches then you'll get null as a result:

```
function isUrl(myString) {
  var match = myString.match('/(?:^|\s)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+(?=\.).)?(?<name>.*).(?<tld>(?<=\.)\w+)/');
  if(match !== null) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```